# expolde field in query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `city` (
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;


INSERT INTO `city` (`city_id`, `city`) VALUES
(1, 'London'),
(2, 'Moscow'),
(3, 'Perth'),
(4, 'tokyo'),
(5, 'seoul');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cities_travel` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`, `user_name`, `cities_travel`) VALUES
(1, 'todd', '5'),
(2, 'martin', '1,2,4');
```

I am trying to display as follows,

1      todd      seoul 
2      martin     London,Moscow,Tokyo

How can I build query so that I will get above our result?

Comment: Not an answer: is there a reason you didn't create a separate `usercity` table? You'd still need to undertake a concatenation task to get your desired output ... but you wouldn't need to unpack the values first (and, without knowing your app's constraints, the separate table feels like a better approach generally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya, better way is to make a separate table "`usercitytrans`" with feids

```
id (auto increment)
user_id 
city_id
```

and then save the data in this transaction table.   so you may have data like

```
id  user_id  city_id
1   1        5
2   1        4
3   1        2
4   2        5
5   1        1
```

in this case, you can get the comma separated cities with this sql

```
     select u.user_id, user_name, 
    group_concat(city_name separator  ', ' ) as usercities   from (user as u left join usercitytrans as ut
            on u.user_id = ut.user_id) left join city as c
            on ut.city_id = c.city_id
where user_id = 1
            group by ut.city_id
```